# eliminate duplicate using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have these 3 **tables**.  I performed the **query** below, but the **query** returns 5 records for 101 and 2 records for 201.

```
questions_tbl                   answers_tbl                 meter_tbl
 qid    qtype  other_columns     qid(fk)  other_columns      qtype      other_columns
  1     101                      1                           101
  2     201                      2                           101
  3     101                      3                           101
  4     101                      4                           201  

SELECT *
FROM answers, meter, questions
WHERE questions.qid=answers.question_id AND questions.subject_type = meter.subject_type
```

ALSO I TRIED DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT
FROM answers, meter, questions
WHERE questions.qid=answers.question_id AND questions.subject_type = meter.subject_type
```

Comment: I tried SELECT DISTINCT seem not to work?

Comment: What query are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, please add your query to your question so that we can help.

Comment: Can you also add sample input and output that you would expect?

Comment: @michael i just added the query

Comment: I guess the secret is in the "other columns" section. Prepare a SqlFiddle sample, then you will get a quick answer...

Comment: I don't see any actual question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try DISTINCT like this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT questions.qtype,other_column FROM answers, meter, questions
 WHERE questions.qid=answers.question_id AND questions.subject_type =  
 meter.subject_type
```

Using GROUP BY

```
 SELECT * FROM answers, meter, questions
 WHERE questions.qid=answers.question_id AND questions.subject_type = meter.subject_type  
 GROUP BY questions.qtype
```